# Seating a matrix in another matrix in Lisp

Tags: matrix, lisp

I've got a 5x5 matrix (2D array)

```lisp
#2A((C C C C C)
    (C C C C C)
    (C C C C C)
    (C C C C C)
    (C C C C C))
```

and a 3x3 matrix

```lisp
#2A((X X X)
    (X X X)
    (X X X))
```

I'd like to seat `d` into the `m` at the index 1x1

```lisp
(defvar *m* (make-array '(5 5) :initial-element 'C ))

(defvar *d* (make-array '(3 3)
            :displaced-to *m*
            :displaced-index-offset (array-row-major-index *m* 1 1)))

(dotimes (i 3)
       (dotimes (j 3)
         (setf (aref *d* i j) 'X)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```lisp
#2A((C C C C C) 
    (C X X X X) 
    (X X X X X) 
    (C C C C C) 
    (C C C C C))
```

**THE DESIRED OUTPUT**

```lisp
#2A((C C C C C)
    (C X X X C)
    (C X X X C)
    (C X X X C)
    (C C C C C))
```

How to arrange the code as practically as possible, to get the desired output? The code doesn't need to use the 2d arrays or its functions. Actually it's preferable not use the 2d arrays at all because for this particular problem, they seem unfit. I've used the 2d arrays solely because I thought they would have the appropriate features to solve this problem. Any other ways to solve the problem are welcome.

System: CLisp on Windows

Comment: You could use http://turtleware.eu/posts/Conformal-array-displacement.html, I can't give a proper answer, maybe tomorrow

Comment: @coredump I've just now seen your comment (after I couldn't see any answer or comment for about 6 hours, I became a bit distanced)  The article is right on point and it almost gives the answer. Actually I thought it qualified as an answer until I noticed that it worked solely on the *LispM* on which the so-called conformal array displacement was possible. The given hack to achieve the same functionality on Common Lisp is good but frankly speaking looks a bit convoluted. Still, all in all it's good to know. I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with displaced arrays.  The reason you can't do it is because arrays are (treated as) contiguous chunks of memory (so, one-dimensional objects), and displaced arrays are are displaced to a given index of another array *considered as a contiguous chunk of memory* and are themselves then also a contiguous objects in memory which share some of the storage of the array they are displaced to.  And the array you want is not contiguous within the one it is displaced to.

To see this, here are two functions: `make-self-indexed-array` makes a two-dimensional array whose elements are lists of the indices of themselves.  `make-rma-displaced-array` then makes a 1-dimensional array which is displaced to another array:

```
(defun make-self-indexed-array (r c)
  (let ((a (make-array (list r c))))
    (dotimes (row r a)
      (dotimes (col c)
        (setf (aref a row col) (list row col))))))

(defun make-rma-displaced-array (array)
  (make-array (array-total-size array)
              :displaced-to array))
```

Then look at this:

```
> (let* ((a (make-self-indexed-array 5 5))
         (b (make-rma-array a)))
    (pprint a)
    (pprint b))

#2A(((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (0 3) (0 4))
    ((1 0) (1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (1 4))
    ((2 0) (2 1) (2 2) (2 3) (2 4))
    ((3 0) (3 1) (3 2) (3 3) (3 4))
    ((4 0) (4 1) (4 2) (4 3) (4 4)))
#((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (0 3) (0 4) (1 0) (1 1) (1 2) (1 3) (1 4) (2 0) (2 1)
  (2 2) (2 3) (2 4) (3 0) (3 1) (3 2) (3 3) (3 4) (4 0) (4 1) (4 2) (4 3)
  (4 4))
```

You can see that the 'displaced' array you want simply is not contiguous within the original array.

To do what you want you'd need to construct some kind of object which does the appropriate index calculations to address its parent in memory.  Here is a very rudimentary approach to doing that (the [link mentioned in a comment](http://turtleware.eu/posts/Conformal-array-displacement.html) is probably much more general).  This

- only deals with 2d-arrays;
- will likely have terrible performance;
- but shows you the sort of thing you need to do.

In real life you can generalise this to arrays of arbitrary shape, doing some cleverness to calculate, effectively, the `row-major-aref` index you need.

```
(defclass 2d-subarray ()
  ;; 2d subarrays of other 2d arrays
  ((parent :reader subarray-parent
           :initarg :parent
           :initform (error "need a parent"))
   (row-offset :initform 0
               :initarg :row-offset
               :reader subarray-row-offset)
   (column-offset :initform 0
                  :initarg :column-offset
                  :reader subarray-column-offset)
   (rows :initform 0
         :initarg :rows
         :reader subarray-rows)
   (columns :initform 0
            :initarg :columns
            :reader subarray-columns)))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((subarray 2d-subarray) &key)
  ;; do at least some sanity checks
  (let ((p (subarray-parent subarray)))
    (unless (= (length (array-dimensions p)) 2)
      (error "parent not 2d"))
    (unless (<= (+ (subarray-row-offset subarray)
                   (subarray-rows subarray))
                (array-dimension p 0))
      (error "subarray has too many rows"))
    (unless (<= (+ (subarray-column-offset subarray)
                   (subarray-columns subarray))
                (array-dimension p 1))
      (error "subarray has too many columns"))))


(defgeneric subarray-aref (subarray &rest indices))
(defgeneric (setf subarray-aref) (new subarray &rest indices))

(defmethod subarray-aref ((subarray 2d-subarray) &rest indices)
  (declare (dynamic-extent indices))
  (destructuring-bind (row column) indices
    (assert (and (<= 0 row (subarray-rows subarray))
                 (<= 0 column (subarray-columns subarray)))
        (row column) "indices out of range")
    (aref (subarray-parent subarray)
          (+ row (subarray-row-offset subarray))
          (+ column (subarray-column-offset subarray)))))

(defmethod (setf subarray-aref) (new (subarray 2d-subarray) &rest indices)
  (declare (dynamic-extent indices))
  (destructuring-bind (row column) indices
    (assert (and (<= 0 row (subarray-rows subarray))
                 (<= 0 column (subarray-columns subarray)))
        (row column) "indices out of range")
    (setf (aref (subarray-parent subarray)
                (+ row (subarray-row-offset subarray))
                (+ column (subarray-column-offset subarray)))
          new)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I acclaim the code for its comprehensive use of CLOS however I don't know enough CLOS to even test the code. I've just edited the original post.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen: well, if you're unable to use the code (I don't see why, but never mind), then surely you can see that what you need to do is *compute the indices of the subarray you want in the array you have*.  That's ... not hard.